# ExtJS 4 adding a loading icon

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4.1

I'm using ExtJS 4.1 and it's a lot faster but yet sometimes loading a view may take a while so I want to show some kind of `Loading` image which will tell the user that he should wait. I suspect that it's something pretty standard but yet some advices on how and where to do it would be very helpful.

Thanks

Leron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for `LoadMask` in their documentation. It is pretty standard thing.

Answer (score 0):

i did like this:

into index.html

```
    <div id="page-loader">  
        <img style="display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; width=50%; height=100%;" src="data/xxxxx.gif" />
        <br/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Initializing...
        <br/>
    </div>
```

into app.js

launch: function() {

```
    Ext.create('Pwallet.view.Videata');
    if (Ext.get('page-loader')) {
        Ext.get('page-loader').remove();}


}
```